# how do I find the possible values of Y?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> A random number $X$ is sampled with the following probability density
>     $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac32x^2(1-x),  & \text{if $x$ is in [-1, 1]} \\
> 0, & \text{else}
> \end{cases}  
> $$
>   We define another random variable by $Y=\frac{1}{X^2}$.

How do I figue out what values Y takes? I have the solution as: Y takes values [1, $\infty$) but I don't know why? can someone explain.
The solution says since X takes values [-1, 1] we have $-1 \le X \le 1$ then since we have $Y=\frac{1}{X^2}$ we get $0 \le X^2 \le 1$, I understand this because since you square X, the values from -1 to 0 become positive. Then the solution states $1 \le \frac{1}{X^2} \le \infty$ therefore Y takes values [1, $\infty$), but I do not understand that last step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One step at a time.

First step.   If $0 \lt X^2$ then $\frac 1{X^2}\lt \infty$ .   Because the inverse of every positive number is a finite number.

Second step.   If $0 < X^2\leq 1$ then $1\leq \frac{1}{X^2}$.    Because the inverse of every positive number no greater than one must be a positive number no lesser than one.

Put it together.   $-1 \leq X\leq 1$ means $1\leq \tfrac 1 {X^2} < \infty$, and therefore $Y \in [1; \infty)$

---

The only problem child is the point $X=0$, because $1/X^2$ is not definite there.   However, we simply ignore this exception because it is a zero measure event.